# Project to return a line in a text file in python from user input

Tags: python, search, return, raw-input

```
code = raw_input("Enter Code: ')
for line in open('test.txt', 'r'):
    if code in line:
        print line
    else:
        print 'Not in file'
```

The test.txt file looks like this

```
A        1234567
AB       2345678
ABC      3456789
ABC1     4567890
```

When input is A
The print line returns all lines with A instead of just the first line. Note: the test.txt file has approximately 2000 entry's. I just want to return the line with the numbers for what ever the user inputs for now

Comment: @juanchopanza I was just DOING that :)

Comment: OP: Your code won't currently run (your quote marks don't match). Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, you're using `in`, which checks if the string `"A"` is in the line. Why would you expect `"AB    2345678"` to not have `"A"` in it? It's right there. At the start. Hint: you probably want `.split()` and `==`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Wooble points out in the comments, the problem is your use of the `in` operator to test for equivalency rather than membership.

```
code = raw_input("Enter Code: ")
for line in open('test.txt', 'r'):
    if code.upper() == line.split()[0].strip().upper():
        print line
    else:
        print 'Not in file'
        # this will print after every line, is that what you want?
```

That said, probably a better idea (dependent on your use case anyway) is to pull the file into a dictionary and use that instead.

```
def load(filename):
    fileinfo = {}
    with open(filename) as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            key,value = map(str.strip, line.split())
            if key in fileinfo:
                # how do you want to handle duplicate keys?
            else:
                fileinfo[key] = value
    return fileinfo
```

Then after you load it all in:

```
def pick(from_dict):
    choice = raw_input("Pick a key: ")
    return from_dict.get(choice, "Not in file")
```

And run as:

```
>>> data = load("test.txt")
>>> print(pick(data))
Pick a key: A
1234567
```

Comment: OP: you attempted to edit my post instead of writing a comment :). To get the values as an integer, just call `int` on them (e.g. in `def pick` do `return from_dict.get(int(choice), "Not in file")`

Comment: Sorry I am first time here. and very new to python. Upon running the script it does return the value of A however the following is also on the next line. <function pick at 0x02414970> memory problem?

Comment: @user3609157 `value = int(pick(data))` will store the value as an int in the variable `value`.